# How to handle notification bar in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: windows, selenium-webdriver

When i am clicking on a link a notification bar is appearing over the same webpage.I am not able to pass control on this notification bar.I have to click on cross link and i have to get the text from it.
Please reply with the solution for this problem.

Comment: Can you please share the relevant HTML Code and/or the code that you've tried so far ?

Comment: Can you provide an image of that? That will be really helpful.

Comment: @Subh thanks for comment,, it is something like a popup when i click on add_to_cart button a pop up is coming over same webpage there is no ok or cancel any type of button,only a text is in between of popup and one close icon link is at right top corner and i have to click on this close link but i am not able to do it.Everytime NoSuchElementException is showing.It is not a alert popup so alert coding is not working.please give me a solution

Comment: @VigneshParamasivam Thanks for reply..How can i use Autoit.its not a window based object..i have mentioned the scenario in above comment please tell me how to do it

Comment: @Subodh :It's better to add an image (for your question) and the relevant html code for the popup, to clarify. I can conjure the popup thing in my mind, but an image of that will make it easier to comprehend. Better yet, if this is a public site, please give the link. Thanks.. :)

Comment: @Subh :I am not able to add image because to add an image on this site i should have 10 reputations but right now i have only one.Ok, by the way i got the solution by applying wait statement for 10 seconds before the driver.findElement(By.xpath("Xpath of Element on popup")).click(); Now I am able to switch control over the popup.Thanks for your reply. :)

Comment: Great... And yes you can upload image to imgur and add the link here.. :)